# set selected value of select field if option with that value does not exist

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set the selected value of a select box if it exists, and to add it to the select box if it does not exist.

How do I do that?

I have:

```
<select id="abc" name="abc">
</select>
```

I want:

```
  $('#abc').val(123);
```

afterwards:

```
<select id="abc" name="abc">
<option value="123" selected>
</select>
```

Comment: `$('#abc').append('<option value="123">123</option>');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the below code.

```
if($('#abc option[value=' + testValue + ']').length === 0) {
    $('#abc').append('<option value="' + testValue + '">' + testValue + '</option>');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can append element

```
var html = '<option value="123">123</option>';
jQuery("#abc").append(html);
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing is that you can use jQuery `append` method to add any html element to your page. In this case, you may need to append an `option` element. So first thing you need is to check if that option exists. If it does not you need to append it into the `select` element. In both cases( whether it exists or not), you can set the value as selected using `val()` method:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  select123();
});//document ready

function select123()
{
  if( ! $("#abc option[value=123]").length )
  {
    $("#abc").append('<option value="123">123</option>');
  }
  $("#abc").val("123");
}//select123
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="abc" name="abc">
</select>
```

Comment: You don;'t need to check for length property

Comment: if there is no element found it will return [] which is evaluted to "" which is false

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN Ok, that seems better, but I am not sure. I've been using `.length` check to check if certain elements exist on a page. I will try as you suggested now. Thanks :)

Comment: You can try this one.  `[].toString()` on your console.

Answer (score 1):

```
var valueExists = $("#abc option[value=123]");
if(!valueExists){

    ("#abc").append('<option>123</option>')
}



$("#abc option[value=123]")
```

will return empty array which is evaluted to `""` so it is false otherwise Array of object of html Collection returned

Answer (score 1):

Check if the value exists using `$("#abc option[value='123']").length > 0` and if not, append.

```js
$(function(){
  var val = '1234';
  
  if($("#abc option[value='123']").length > 0){
    alert('present')
  }
  else {
   var s = '<option value=' + val + '>' + val + '</option>';
   $('#abc').append(s);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="abc" name="abc">
<option value="123" selected>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code can help you started.

1. If the value is already present, then set it as the selected option.
2. Else append the value to dropdown.

**Scenario 1: Value already exists in dropdown. So just select it.**

```js
$(function() {
  var val = '1';
  var exists = false;

  $('#abc option').each(function() {
    if (this.value == val) {
      $('#abc').val(val);
      exists = true;
      return false;
    }
  });

  if (exists == false) {
    $('#abc').append('<option value="' + val + '" selected>' + val + '</option>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="abc" name="abc">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

---

**Scenario 2: Value not in dropdown. So append it.**

```js
$(function() {
  var val = '123';
  var exists = false;

  $('#abc option').each(function() {
    if (this.value == val) {
      $('#abc').val(val);
      exists = true;
      return false;
    }
  });

  if (exists == false) {
    $('#abc').append('<option value="' + val + '" selected>' + val + '</option>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="abc" name="abc">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```